# How DriverKit driver notify application?

Tags: macos, iokit, driverkit

I know how to send data to DriverKit and get back some values, that is application calling `IOConnectCallStructMethod()` and driver fill the `OSData` in `structureOutput` from application.

In my Application it is using `IOConnectCallAsyncScalarMethod()` and the kext using `sendAsyncResult64()` to let the app know events coming in. However the method `sendAsyncResult64()` is not available in DriverKit.

I saw [AsyncCompletion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/iouserclient/3325613-asynccompletion?language=occ) looks like solution but no idea to implement it. Anyone know how to do?
Appreciate if any suggestion!

Comment: By the way in my app I use `IOConnectCallStructMethod` and prepares a buffer for driver, and in my driver use `IOMemoryDescriptor::CreateMapping` to fill related data let app get it. But I don't know how to use `IOMemoryDescriptor::CreateMapping` in successful way.

Answer (score 6):

`IOUserClient::AsyncCompletion` is indeed the replacement for `sendAsyncResult64()`.

To call it successfully, you need to retain the `OSAction` object supplied in the `completion` field of the `IOUserClientMethodArguments` supplied in your `ExternalMethod` dispatch function. Then, when you are ready to send an asynchronous result, call

```
userclient->AsyncCompletion(saved_osaction, result, async_arguments, num_async_arguments);
```

Don't forget to release the `OSAction` object once you no longer need it. The array of async arguments will be passed to the handler function in the user space application, same as with a kext calling `sendAsyncResult64()`.

Note that you can't asynchronously fill "small" `structureOutput` fields (4096 bytes or less) as these must be returned in the `ExternalMethod` handler. Only if the buffer is large enough to be passed via `structureOutputDescriptor` can you retain that descriptor and fill it with data after the initial `ExternalMethod` returns. This is no different than for kexts, however.

Comment: We solved this problem by you indication, thanks :) You're the top!